Divisibility of Gromov-Witten invariants
We know if a smooth complex projective variety $X$ is Fano, when the insertions of Gromov-Witten invariants are integral cohomology classes $\alpha_i \in H^*(X; {\mathbb Z})$, in genus zero the (primary) Gromov-Witten invariants $GW_{0, k}(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_k)$ are always integers.
I wonder if there are any example of Fano manifold whose genus zero Gromov-Witten invariants (with integral insertions) are ALWAYS even numbers (or more generally, divisible by some prime)?

Does the related problem in open Gromov Witten theory has any interest for you?
